# Letter number combo to float in python

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, stellargraph

```
def computefeatures(node_id):
    return [ord(node_id), len(node_id)]
```

I am computing features for my node ids which are a combo of a letter and a number. ord will not work, is there another work around for this.

my list is:

```
ln0
Out[88]: 
0     C1
1     C2
2     C3
3     C4
4     C5
5     C6
6     G1
7     I1
8     O1
9     P1
10    P2
11    P3
12    R1
13    R2
14    R3
15    R4
16    R5
17    R6
dtype: object
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. What is the input? What should be the output?

Comment: The first issue is that it seems like you're passing a string like 'C1' to the 'ord' function. ord() takes a char (single character), not a string. Beyond that you'll need to provide more information for any meaningful help

Comment: Apologies, each of the letter number combos is the label of a node in the graph. I am trying to compute a simple node feature using the node id. A float is required.

Comment: Are you trying to come up with an essentially arbitrary hashing of node id's to floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your node consist of a single letter followed by an integer, and all you want to do is map them to floats, this can be done in various ways.

One way is to convert your node_id into a hex string of the sort that is returned by the float method `hex` (for example, `(3.14).hex() = '0x1.91eb851eb851fp+1'`). Take the `ord` of the letter, convert it to a hexstring, and use it as the decimal part of the mantissa. Take the integer part and use it as the exponent. Once you create the string, map it to a float using the class method `float.fromhex`:

```
def compute_feature(node_id):
    n = ord(node_id[0])
    i = node_id[1:]
    hex_string = '0x1.' + hex(n)[2:] + 'p+' + i
    return float.fromhex(hex_string)
```

For example,

```
>>> compute_feature('C1')
2.5234375
```

This approach has the nice feature that you can use the float method `hex` and a small amount of parsing to recover the node id from the float.